# Change List column type to Guid in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, project

I have a List in SharePoint (as part of a ProjectOnline solution). I would like to add a column to this list - of type Guid.

But I am not allowed to specify this at creation time (I can specify all sorts of other types like "Text", "HyperLink", "Date" etc).

How do I do this? Is there some special powershell-magic I can use?

Comment: There are no Guid type column on Sharepoint, you can use a Text column

Comment: @Max apparently there is :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this way to create a Guid column on a SharePoint list:

```
ListCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
creationInfo.Title = listTitle;
creationInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Announcements;
List list = _subSiteWeb.Lists.Add(creationInfo);
list.Description = listDescription;

list.Update();
_subSitecontext.ExecuteQuery();

_subSitecontext.Load(_subSiteWeb, w => w.Lists);
_subSitecontext.ExecuteQuery();

var spList = _subSiteWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var field = spList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field DisplayName='MyField2' Type='Guid' />",
                                true,
                                AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue); 

var fldNumber = _subSitecontext.CastTo<FieldNumber>(field);
fldNumber.Update();

_subSitecontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This will create a new SharePoint list and add a column to it of type Guid.